# Automatically writing histograms to external folder in r

Tags: r

I have a large number of data frames with a large number of variables and I need to produce histograms for each variable (which explicitly name the variable used). I like to have these in the RStudio interface (not a popout) and I also need to have these images saved as jpegs in a folder.

I have a loop that I use to generate histograms of all the variables, but this does not label each histogram for each element and it also has the histograms exported as a popout rather than an image in RStudio (example data frame and loop provided below).

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$A <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,16)
df$B <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$C <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df_col_names <- df %>% select(A:C) %>% colnames(.) 


for(df_col_names in df) {
  dev.new()
  hist(df_col_names) # subset with [] not $
}
```

I also have code to create a jpeg for each histogram, but unsure how to loop this so it creates a new image for each variable, with the file name labelled and the image labelled with the variable name.

```
jpeg(filename = "C:\\Images\\hist.jpg")
hist(df$A, main="A" , xlab="A", breaks = 10)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lapply` to iterate over column names. Subset them using `[[`, give title and x-axis label to the plot based on column name and write the plot as an image.

```
lapply(df_col_names, function(x) {
  jpeg(filename=sprintf('C:\\Images\\%s.jpeg', x))
  hist(df[[x]], main = x, xlab = x, breaks = 10)
  dev.off()
})
```

This should create 3 plots in your Images folder named `"A.jpeg"`, `"B.jpeg"` and `"C.jpeg"`.

Answer (score 1):

I understood you want the histograms in both, files and the plots window, i.e. you want to access multiple devices. Using `dev.copy`, the code would be:

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 3))  #
lapply(names(df)[-1], function(x) {
  hist(df[[x]], main=x, xlab=x, breaks=10)
  dev.copy(png, filename=paste0("plot_", x, ".png"))
  dev.off()
})
par(op)  #
```

I use `png` which is better for this kind of images, else simply change "png` to "jpg".

If you prefer the plots in the window consecutively rather than side by side, leave out the lines with the `#`.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:16, A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 14, NA, NA, NA, 16), B = c(10, 0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 12, 12, 0, 
14, NA, 14, 16, 16, 16, 16), C = c(10, 12, 14, 16, 10, 12, 14, 
16, 10, 12, 14, 16, 10, 12, 14, 16)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```